# Problem with counting number of visitors in my smart room

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors, infrared

[image: Mealy Diagram]I'm building a visitor counter in my room using Arduino, IR transmitter, and two SHARP IR sensors.
The sensors count the number of people in my room - one person turns up the light, more do nothing, and zero turns the light off.
The IR transmitter works great (it turns the light on/off) so as the detection, but I have a problem and a question.

My question is, is there an option to make a function and call it twice instead of repeating myself inside the loop? if so, how? they are mostly symmetric, but still have some differences like the flags and num_people manipulating.

My main problem right now is counting num_people and I found out that this line is the problem: `num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people-1 : 0;`
When I put this line in a comment I can count more than one person, but when I'm not it runs over the code and counts 1,0,1,0,1,0 (only when getting inside the room). Need to say that when I go out it decreases num_people as it should and when on zero keeps that number.

The code is here:

```
/*
    Smart Light V1.0 Software
    ==========================
    Copyright (C) 2020 Yuval Kedar - KD Tech
    The program counts visitors in my room and controls the light using SHARP IR sensors
    Board: Arduino Pro Mini
*/


#include "Arduino.h"
#include <IRremote.h>
// TODO: try a dedicated library for the sensors. Raw readings aren't the best way to do that - need to overcome oversampling, debouncing, hysteresis, etc.

#define IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN  (3)
#define SENS_1_PIN (A1)
#define SENS_2_PIN (A0)

#define SENS_1_MIN  (160)
#define SENS_2_MIN  (160)
#define MAX_TIME    (1000)
#define IR_KEY      (0x68B92)
#define DEBOUNCE_MS (300)

IRsend irsend;

uint8_t num_people = 0;
uint8_t prev_num_people = 0;
bool sens_1_flag = 0;
bool sens_2_flag = 0;
uint32_t timeout;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(SENS_1_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(SENS_2_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println(F(
                "_______________________________\n"
                "\n"
                "      S M A R T    R O O M     \n"
                "_______________________________\n"
                "\n"
                "      Made by KD Technology    \n"
                "\n"));
}

void loop() {
    uint16_t sens_1_val = analogRead(SENS_1_PIN);
    uint16_t sens_2_val = analogRead(SENS_2_PIN);
    /*
    Serial.print("LDR 1: ");
    Serial.print(sens_1_val);
    Serial.print("\t LDR 2: ");
    Serial.println(sens_2_val);
    delay(200);
    */

    //TODO: there is a duplication here. Create a function and call it twice inside the loop.

    //Someone goes in
    if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_2_flag = 1;
    if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 1) {
        // TODO: add timeout to while loop. Otherwise, the program will stuck because of a sensor reading.
        // timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;
        // while (sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && (millis() > timeout));
        num_people = num_people+1;
        if (num_people == 1 && prev_num_people == 0) {
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
        sens_1_flag = 0;
        sens_2_flag = 0;
        prev_num_people = num_people;           
        Serial.print("People in the room: ");
        Serial.println(num_people);
        delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
    }

    //Someone goes out
    if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_1_flag = 1;
    if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 1 && sens_2_flag == 0) {
        timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;
        while (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && (millis() > timeout));
        num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people-1 : 0;
        if (num_people == 0 && prev_num_people != 0) {
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
        sens_1_flag = 0;
        sens_2_flag = 0;
        prev_num_people = num_people;           
        Serial.print("People in the room: ");
        Serial.println(num_people);
        delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
/*
    Smart Light V1.0 Software
    ==========================
    Copyright (C) 2020 Yuval Kedar - KD Tech
    The program counts visitors in my room and controls the light using SHARP IR sensors
    Board: Arduino Pro Mini
*/


#include "Arduino.h"
#include <IRremote.h>
// TODO: try a dedicated library for the sensors. Raw readings aren't the best way to do that - need to overcome oversampling, debouncing, hysteresis, etc.

#define IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN  (3)
#define SENS_1_PIN (A1)
#define SENS_2_PIN (A0)

#define SENS_1_MIN  (160)
#define SENS_2_MIN  (160)
#define MAX_TIME    (1000)
#define IR_KEY      (0x68B92)
#define DEBOUNCE_MS (300)

IRsend irsend;

uint8_t num_people = 0;
uint8_t prev_num_people = 0;
bool sens_1_flag = 0;
bool sens_2_flag = 0;
uint32_t timeout;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(SENS_1_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(SENS_2_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println(F(
                "_______________________________\n"
                "\n"
                "      S M A R T    R O O M     \n"
                "_______________________________\n"
                "\n"
                "      Made by KD Technology    \n"
                "\n"));
}

void loop() {
    uint16_t sens_1_val = analogRead(SENS_1_PIN);
    uint16_t sens_2_val = analogRead(SENS_2_PIN);
    /*
    Serial.print("LDR 1: ");
    Serial.print(sens_1_val);
    Serial.print("\t LDR 2: ");
    Serial.println(sens_2_val);
    delay(200);
    */

    //TODO: there is a duplication here. Create a function and call it twice inside the loop.

    //Someone goes in
    if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_2_flag = 1;
    if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 1) {
        // TODO: add timeout to while loop. Otherwise, the program will stuck because of a sensor reading.
        // timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;
        // while (sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && (millis() > timeout));
        num_people += 1;
        if (num_people == 1 && prev_num_people == 0) {
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
        sens_1_flag = 0;
        sens_2_flag = 0;
        prev_num_people = num_people;           
        Serial.print("People in the room: ");
        Serial.println(num_people);
        delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
    }

    //Someone goes out
    if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_1_flag = 1;
    if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 1 && sens_2_flag == 0) {
        // timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;
        // while (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && (millis() > timeout));
        // num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people-1 : 0;
        if (num_people > 1) num_people -= 1;
        if (num_people == 1 && prev_num_people != 0) {
            num_people -= 1;
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
        sens_1_flag = 0;
        sens_2_flag = 0;
        prev_num_people = num_people;           
        Serial.print("People in the room: ");
        Serial.println(num_people);
        delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
    }
}
```

DIFFERENT APPROACH:

I figured out the new machine state. There are 4 states I need to pass:
 1. sens_1 detects and sens_2 doesn't
 2. both sensors detect
 3. sens_2 detect and sens_1 doesn't
 4. none of them detects.

Here is my code:

```
/*
    Smart Light V1.0 Software
    ==========================
    Copyright (C) 2020 Yuval Kedar - KD Tech
    The program counts visitors in my room and controls the light using SHARP IR sensors
    Board: Arduino Pro Mini
*/


#include "Arduino.h"
#include <IRremote.h>
// TODO: try a dedicated library for the sensors. Raw readings aren't the best way to do that - need to overcome oversampling, debouncing, hysteresis, etc.

#define IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN  (3)
#define SENS_1_PIN (A0)
#define SENS_2_PIN (A1)

#define SENS_1_MIN  (115)
#define SENS_2_MIN  (115)
#define IR_KEY      (0x68B92)
#define DEBOUNCE_MS (2000)


IRsend irsend;

int8_t num_people = 0;
uint8_t state = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(SENS_1_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(SENS_2_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println(F(
                "_______________________________\n"
                "\n"
                "      S M A R T    R O O M     \n"
                "_______________________________\n"
                "\n"
                "      Made by KD Technology    \n"
                "\n"));
}

void loop() {
    uint16_t sens_1_val = analogRead(SENS_1_PIN);
    uint16_t sens_2_val = analogRead(SENS_2_PIN);
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            if ((sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN) && (sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN)) {
            // if (!sens_1_val && sens_2_val) {
                state = 4;
                Serial.println("0 to 4");
            }
            if ((sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN) && (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN)) {
            // if (!sens_2_val && sens_1_val) {
                state = 1;
                Serial.println("0 to 1");
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if ((sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN) && (sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN)) {
            // if (!sens_1_val && !sens_2_val) {
                state = 2;
                Serial.println("1 to 2");
            } else state = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            if ((sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN) && (sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN)) {
            // if (!sens_1_val && sens_2_val) {
                state = 3;
                Serial.println("2 to 3");
            } else state = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            if ((sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN) && (sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN)) {   //someone went out
            // if (sens_1_val && sens_2_val) {  //someone went out
                num_people -= 1;
                if (num_people == 0) {
                    irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
                    Serial.println("BLING!");
                }
                else if (num_people == -1) num_people = 0;
                Serial.print("People in the room: ");
                Serial.println(num_people);
                // delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
                state = 0;
            }  else state = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            if ((sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN) && (sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN)) {
            // if (!sens_1_val && !sens_2_val) {
                state = 5;
                Serial.println("4 to 5");
            } else state = 0;
            break;
        case 5:
            if ((sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN) && (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN)) {
            // if (!sens_2_val && sens_1_val) {
                state = 6;
                Serial.println("5 to 6");
            } else state = 4;
            break;
        case 6:
            if ((sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN) && (sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN)) {   //someone came in
            // if (sens_1_val && sens_2_val) {  //someone came in
                num_people += 1;
                if (num_people == 1) {
                    irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
                    Serial.println("BLING!");
                }
                Serial.print("People in the room: ");
                Serial.println(num_people);
                // delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
                state = 0;
            } else state = 5;
            break;
    }
    // Serial.print("LDR 1: ");
    // Serial.print(sens_1_val);
    // Serial.print("\t LDR 2: ");
    // Serial.println(sens_2_val);
    // delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
}
```

I first checked the code with buttons and digital readings and it worked perfectly! But then, when I went back to analog readings a problem came up: I printed to the serial monitor a string at each state to find the problem and noticed that it passes all the states but when it reaches the last state and suppose to increase\decrease num_people and print it as well it doesn't. Instead it goes back to state 0...

Comment: Normally pictures in posts are frowned upon, but in this case, it will help to illustrate your code. and to determine if adjustments are needed in your logic.  Please edit your post and include a simple diagram/picture showing (and labeling) your sensor layout in relation to the door.  Include location of door, location(s) of sensors mentioned in post relative to the door.

Comment: Select C or C++.  Unnecessary dual tagging attracts down-votes.

Comment: @ryyker Spellling is knot mi strong sute.  Comment amended.

Comment: I attached the two sensors horizontally (one next to the other) on the side of the doorpost - that way I can know if someone went in or out of the room (which sensor detected first)

Comment: Your state machine is 'strange' (I mean I think invalid). I am not sure to understand the red transition, is it possible for someone in the room to manually put the light off ? If yes it must be possible to put if on too. Still if yes to be sure the on/off command is *inside* the room only ?

Comment: BTW you do *sens_x_val > SENS_1_MIN* and *sens_x_val < SENS_1_MIN* but that does not manage the *sens_x_val* **==** *SENS_1_MIN*. You have to replace < by <= or (exclusive) > by >= in all your tests

Comment: I simulated your hardware and all seems ok out of the problem when a sensor returns exactly SENS_x_MIN. Visibly  when a person cross sensor1 then sensor2 the sequence is *(sensor1 > MIN && sensor1 < MIN)* then *(sensor1 > MIN && sensor2 > MIN)* then *(sensor1 < MIN && sensor2 > MIN)* then *(sensor1 < MIN && sensor2 < MIN)*. Of course you will have to manage other sequences where someone come back in front of one/two sensors

Comment: I changed it, but it doesn't really matter. The readings are much higher than that

Comment: a distance of 2 cm is very few, if you catch an arm and that one 'come back' you will have a sequence concerning the sensors you do not manage

Comment: I managed the other options as well. The else in each of the states does that. I checked everything and it works really good with digital readings and buttons, but as I said with analog readings there is a problem... not sure what

Comment: ok in that case I am afraid I cannot hep you more.

Comment: Tnx anyway, you were VERY helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an option to make a function and call it twice instead of repeating myself inside the loop? if so, how? they are mostly symmetric, but still have some differences like the flags and num_people manipulating.

For sure your two parts are very similar, and this is more visible changing the order of the expressions in the 2 ifs.

For instance in the second part you have

> ```
> if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_1_flag = 1;
> if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 1 && sens_2_flag == 0) {
> ```

which is equivalent of that after reordering :

```
if (sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_flag == 0 && sens_1_flag == 0) sens_1_flag = 1;
if (sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_flag == 0 && sens_1_flag == 1) {
```

so exactly the two tests in the first part when exchanging *sens_1_val* with *sens_2_val* and *SENS_1_MIN* with *SENS_2_MIN*, and it is the same in the rest of the lines.

Then :

```
void f(int sens1, int sens1_min, int sens2,int sens2_min, int offset, int bling)
{
    if (sens1 < sens1_min && sens2 > sens2_min && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_2_flag = 1;
    if (sens1 > sens1_min && sens2 < sens2_min && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 1) {
        timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;
        while (sens2 > sens2_min && (millis() > timeout));
        if ((num_people += offset) < 0)
          num_people = 0;
        Serial.print("People in the room: ");
        Serial.println(num_people);
        sens_1_flag = 0;
        sens_2_flag = 0;
        delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
        if (num_people == bling) {
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
    }
}
```

the first part in your code is done by

```
 f(sens_1_val, SENS_1_MIN, sens_2_val, SENS_2_MIN, 1, 1);
 sens_1_val = sens_2_val = 0;
```

and the second by

```
f(sens_2_val, SENS_2_MIN, sens_1_val, SENS_1_MIN, -1, 0); 
sens_1_val = sens_2_val = 0;
```

I did not wanted to reset the *sens_x_val* in the function to not have to give a pointer

For the rest sorry but I do not understand your problem, explain it more

---

**edit after you added the state machine**

Your state machine is strange, I think you do not need so many states. The machine definition depends on if the light can be put off/on manually by someone inside and/or outside of the room.

If the light is only commanded by your sensors more a timeout in case nobody went out nor come in after a time :

[image]

I use here UML notation, in the transition a '[]' indicate a guard/condition to respect else the transition cannot be done, the body after the '/' is executed after the transition is done.

To manage the case where several persons come out at the same time but the sensors count only one I use a timeout.

If the light can be also commanded by someone *inside* the room, and the light is forced on when someone come in, and the light is forced off when the room becomes empty / after the timeout :

[image]

---

**edit, found initial problem**

In your initial version your problem was in :

> ```
>    num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people-1 : 0;
>    ...
>    if (num_people == 0) {
>        irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
>        Serial.println("BLING!");
>    }
> ```

because when you do the test in the *if* you do not know if your light is on or off, you lost that information in the first line, and you can wrongly decide to change its state.

**edit after your code editing**

For me your new code seems ok, anyway you can do without *prev_num_people*.

You set *prev_num_people* to *num_people* after each in/out, so in the case "come in" :

> ```
>    num_people = num_people+1;
>    if (num_people == 1 && prev_num_people == 0) {
>      irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
>      Serial.println("BLING!");
>    }
> ```

before to increment *num_people* you had *prev_num_people == num_people* then after having *num_people == 1* implies *prev_num_people == 0* and it is useless to test it. Just do

```
if (++num_people == 1) {
   /* light is off, put it on */
   irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
   Serial.println("BLING!");
 }
```

In the case "went out" rather than to do

> ```
>    num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people-1 : 0;
>    if (num_people == 0 && prev_num_people != 0) {
>        irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
>        Serial.println("BLING!");
>    }
> ```

just do

```
 if (--num_people == 0) {
    /* light is on, put it off */
    irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
    Serial.println("BLING!");
 }
 else if (num_people == -1) {
    /* light is already off but in past several person
       went out at the same time and only one was count */
    num_people = 0;
 }
```

All of that supposes you detect rightly someone come in / went out, I cannot help you for that, I don't know how your sensors work.

Note if you want to allow a manual change of the light you need to memorize the state of the light, *NumPerson* is not anymore sufficient to decide what is the current state of the light.

---

**edit about your new version containing:**

> ```
>    if (num_people > 1) num_people -= 1;
>    if (num_people == 1 && prev_num_people != 0) {
>        num_people -= 1;
>        irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
>        Serial.println("BLING!");
>    }
> ```

this is 'disturbing' because when you reach the second *if* you only know where you come from thank to *prev_num_people* (*num_people* lost the history), and you do a lot of tests for nothing

I strongly encourage you to use the simplified version I given you before without *prev_num_people*. The more a code is simple, the more it is easy to read and the more it is robust

---

**edit to add simulation**

If I simulate your sensors, your code is disabled by "#if 0" :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num_people = 0;
  int real_people = 0;
  int n;

  while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    real_people += n;

    //Someone goes in
#if 0
    if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_2_flag = 1;
    if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 1)
#else
    if (n > 0)
#endif
    {
      if (++num_people == 1) {
        /* light is off, put it on */
#if 0
        irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
        Serial.println("BLING!");
#else
        puts("put light on");
#endif
      }
#if 0
      sens_1_flag = 0;
      sens_2_flag = 0;
      Serial.print("People in the room: ");
      Serial.println(num_people);
      delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
#else
      printf("People supposed the room: %d (real %d)\n", num_people, real_people);
#endif
    }

    //Someone goes out
#if 0
    if (sens_1_val > SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val < SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 0 && sens_2_flag == 0) sens_1_flag = 1;
    if (sens_1_val < SENS_1_MIN && sens_2_val > SENS_2_MIN && sens_1_flag == 1 && sens_2_flag == 0)
#else
    if (n < 0)
#endif
    {
      if (--num_people == 0) {
        /* light is on, put it off */
#if 0
        irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
        Serial.println("BLING!");
#else
        puts("put light off");
#endif
      }
      else if (num_people == -1) {
        /* light is already off but in past several person
           went out at the same time and only one was count */
        num_people = 0;
      }
#if 0
      sens_1_flag = 0;
      sens_2_flag = 0;
      prev_num_people = num_people;           
      Serial.print("People in the room: ");
      Serial.println(num_people);
      delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
#else
      printf("People supposed the room: %d (real %d)\n", num_people, real_people);
#endif
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

to enter a positive number correspond to the "come in" case, a negative number a "want out". I also added *real_people* corresponding to the real number of people in the room

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall light.c 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1
put light on
People supposed the room: 1 (real 1)
-1
put light off
People supposed the room: 0 (real 0)
1
put light on
People supposed the room: 1 (real 1)
1
People supposed the room: 2 (real 2)
-1
People supposed the room: 1 (real 1)
1
People supposed the room: 2 (real 2)
-1
People supposed the room: 1 (real 1)
-1
put light off
People supposed the room: 0 (real 0)
2
put light on
People supposed the room: 1 (real 2)
-1
put light off
People supposed the room: 0 (real 1)
-1
People supposed the room: 0 (real 0)
1
put light on
People supposed the room: 1 (real 1)
1
People supposed the room: 2 (real 2)
-2
People supposed the room: 1 (real 0)
^C
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Without a timeout on no come-in / went-out the light cannot become off from the end except if 2 people come-in at the same time then 1 went-out then again 1 went-out

Anyway you see the algorithm is ok, so if you have a problem this is in the sensor management (code disabled by #if 0#)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212053/discussion-on-answer-by-bruno-problem-with-counting-number-of-visitors-in-my-sma).

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, your syntax for the ternary operator is wrong, should be like:

```
(condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)
```

So it should be like this:

```
num_people > 0 ? num_people-- : num_people = 0;
```

Is the same as:

```
if (num_people > 0)
{
 num_people--;
}
else
{
 num_people = 0;
}
```

If you want to use a function, why not like this?

```
void MyFuntion(uint16_t& SensVal, uint8_t const MinSensVal, uint8_t& NumPeople)
{
  timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;
  while (SensVal > MinSensVal && (millis() > timeout));
  NumPeople++;
  Serial.print("People in the room: ");
  Serial.println(num_people);
}
```

You don`t have to put everything in the function, just the code which has same structure.

Comment: "it should be like this: `num_people > 0 ? num_people-- : num_people = 0;`"   --> OP's `num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people-1 : 0;` is fine.

Comment: `SensVal > MinSensVal` is  unchanging, either true or false. as neither is `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This isn't so much an answer to the single line you have in your question, but a simplification/cleanup of your code [along the lines your comments suggested].

I had difficulty understanding your logic [with all the replication], so I simplified it as a first step. While I was doing this, others have responded, so you could incorporate their answers if you wish.

Rather than hardwire everything I created a `struct` that fully describes each device and some functions that act on the values in that struct.

Anyway, here's the code. I tried hard to *not* break your existing logic, but you may want to check it. Hopefully, the simplification will allow you to see the real problem more easily:

```
/*
    Smart Light V1.0 Software
    ==========================
    Copyright (C) 2020 Yuval Kedar - KD Tech
    The program counts visitors in my room and controls the light using
    SHARP IR sensors
    Board: Arduino Pro Mini
*/

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <IRremote.h>
// TODO: try a dedicated library for the sensors. Raw readings aren't the best
// way to do that - need to overcome oversampling, debouncing, hysteresis, etc.

#define IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN  (3)
#define SENS_1_PIN (A1)
#define SENS_2_PIN (A0)

#define SENS_1_MIN  (160)
#define SENS_2_MIN  (160)
#define MAX_TIME    (1000)
#define IR_KEY      (0x68B92)
#define DEBOUNCE_MS (300)

IRsend irsend;

typedef struct {
    int sens_id;
    int sens_pin;
    int sens_min;
    int sens_flag;
    uint16_t sens_val;
} sens_t;

sens_t sensall[2];
#define s1  (&sensall[0])
#define s2  (&sensall[1])

uint8_t num_people = 0;
uint32_t timeout;

void
sensinit(sens_t *sens,int id,int pin,int min)
{

    sens->sens_id = id;
    sens->sens_pin = pin;
    sens->sens_min = min;
    sens->sens_flag = 0;
    pinMode(sens->sens_pin,INPUT);
}

void
sensread(sens_t *sens)
{
    sens->sens_val = analogRead(sens->sens_pin);
}

void
setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    sensinit(s1,1,SENS_1_PIN,SENS_1_MIN);
    sensinit(s2,2,SENS_2_PIN,s2->sens_min);

    pinMode(IR_TRANSMITTER_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println(F("_______________________________\n"
        "\n"
        "      S M A R T    R O O M     \n"
        "_______________________________\n"
        "\n"
        "      Made by KD Technology    \n"
        "\n"));
}

int
sensif(int lt_gt,int v1,int v2)
{
    int cond1;
    int cond2;
    int match;

    if (lt_gt) {
        cond1 = (s1->sens_val < s1->sens_min);
        cond2 = (s2->sens_val > s2->sens_min);
    }
    else {
        cond1 = (s1->sens_val > s1->sens_min);
        cond2 = (s2->sens_val < s2->sens_min);
    }

    match = (cond1 && cond2 && (s1->sens_flag == v1) && (s2->sens_flag == v2));

    return match;
}

void
senswait(sens_t *sens,int newval)
{
    timeout = millis() + MAX_TIME;

    // TODO: add timeout to while loop. Otherwise, the program will stuck
    // because of a sensor reading.
    while ((sens->sens_val > sens->sens_min) && (millis() > timeout));

#if 0
    switch (sens->sens_id) {
    case 1:
        num_people = (num_people > 0) ? num_people - 1 : 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        num_people = num_people + 1;
        break;
    }
#else
    num_people = newval;
#endif

    Serial.print("People in the room: ");
    Serial.println(num_people);

    // FIXME -- why clear both instead of just one (e.g. sens->sens_flag)???
    s1->sens_flag = 0;
    s2->sens_flag = 0;

    delay(DEBOUNCE_MS);
}

void
loop(void)
{

    sensread(s1);
    sensread(s2);

#if 0
    Serial.print("LDR 1: ");
    Serial.print(s1->s1_val);
    Serial.print("\t LDR 2: ");
    Serial.println(s2->sens_val);
    delay(200);
#endif

    // Someone goes in
    if (sensif(1,0,0))
        s2->sens_flag = 1;

    if (sensif(0,0,1)) {
        senswait(s2,num_people + 1);
        if (num_people == 1) {
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
    }

    // Someone goes out
    if (sensif(0,0,0))
        s1->sens_flag = 1;

    if (sensif(1,1,0)) {
        senswait(s1,(num_people > 0) ? num_people - 1 : 0);
        if (num_people == 0) {
            irsend.sendSony(IR_KEY, 20);
            Serial.println("BLING!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx, but it looks much more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Hmm ... Having a `struct` based approach with an array of sensors is the way to go. It's ultimately easier. Suppose you had 5000 sensors to manage? What would you do? This approach is what the [linux] kernel does. I've written 20+ commercial grade unix/linux device drivers in my time, and the per-device struct is almost always the first step.

Comment: You totally right, but I'm using only two sensors to detect if a person came in\out. Hence, simple code is the right way for me.

Comment: Alas, you _don't_ have simple code. You have needlessly complex spaghetti code. Using (e.g.) `foo_1/foo_2` instead of an array `foo[2]` is bad enough. But, then, magnifying this across four separate variables for a total of 8 just compounds the problem. What happens when you add another per-device variable [or two or three]? Also, your code is highly unmodular. You're replicating virtually identical code for each sensor instead of using functions.

Comment: And, I believe you said: _My question is, is there an option to make a function and call it twice instead of repeating myself inside the loop? if so, how? they are mostly symmetric, but still have some differences like the flags and num_people manipulating._ Seriously, what form do you expect such a solution to take?